# Как подключить Bluetooth геймпад к любой игре?

Tags: steam, microsoft-store

Проблема заключается в том, что если вы подключаете свой сторонний геймпад по Bluetooth, многие игры не будут его видеть. Есть множество программ, которые позволяют нажатием на геймпад эмулировать клавиатуру, но сейчас речь не об этом. Меня интересует, чтобы игры видели геймпад.

Answer (score 0):

- Steam предоставляет прекрасную возможность настроить любой геймпад, поэтому игры с данной платформы точно будут работать корректно.
- Если же игра не из Steam, её можно добавить как стороннюю и использовать те же настройки.
- Но игры из Microsoft Store сложно добавить в Steam. Например, если вы хотите поиграть в Asphalt 9 на Bluetooth геймпаде, вам потребуется эмулятор. Я предлагаю x360ce. Скачать эмулятор можно на сайте [www.x360ce.com](http://www.x360ce.com).

Надеюсь, я кому-то помог. Удачи!